# Props are undefind when using StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator, react-props

I am new to React native and I have an issue with undefined props while using the `StackNavigator` component in React-Native.

I've spent some days looking an answer for my question, but didn't find a propper way to resolve an issue.

**The issue is in passing props to child component, they are undefined, but, the tutorial i followed is not doing anything else except of these steps.**

***Here screens and code of my app***

[image]

**When hitting green button in my LoginScreen the expected result is navigation to my MainScreen, but the result is "props are undefined"**

[image]

I would be very gratful if someone can help me to solve this problem and help me to figure out, where the problem is!

My code :

App.js file

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
 import Login from './src/components/login/Login';
 import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
 import MainScreen from './src/components/main/MainScreen';

 export default class App extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', header: null };
   render() {
     return (
     <AppNavigation />
     );
    }
 }
  const AppNavigation = StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen : {screen : Login},
    MainScreen : {screen : MainScreen},
  })
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#3498db',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Login.js , this component describes my Login page. It also renders component LoginForm, where i'm describing InputText and TouchableOpacity where i have onPress method, which must navigate me to MainScreen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', header: null };


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
            <Image
              source = {require('../../../images/logo.png')}
              style = {styles.logo}>
            </Image>
            <Text style = {styles.title}>Добро пожаловать!</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.titleLower}>Введите код для         авторизации</Text>
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.formContainer}>
        <LoginForm/>
      </View>
  </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex : 1,
    backgroundColor : '#3493db'
  },
  logoContainer : {
    flexGrow : 1,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent : 'center'
  },
  logo : {
    width : 120,
    height : 120
  },
  title : {
    color : '#fff',
    marginBottom : 10,
    fontSize : 22
  },
  titleLower : {
    color : '#fff',
    marginTop : 5,
    fontSize : 12
  }
});
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StatusBar
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (


  <KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior="padding"
  style={styles.container}>

    <TextInput
       placeholder = "ваш пароль"
       placeholderTextColor = '#fff'
       underlineColorAndroid = {'transparent'}
       style = {styles.input}
       secureTextEntry>
     </TextInput>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style= {styles.buttonContainer}
      onPress = {() =>
        this
        .props
        .navigation
        .navigate('MainScreen')}>
        <Text  style= {styles.buttonText}>Войти</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>


);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  input : {
    backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    height : 40,
    marginBottom : 10,
    color : '#FFF',
    fontSize : 16
  },
  buttonContainer : {
    backgroundColor : '#00B241',
    paddingVertical : 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom : 30
  },
  buttonText : {
    textAlign : 'center',
    color : '#fff'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that LoginForm.js is nested inside of login.js.
So, when you call `this.props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen')`, loginForm.js has no idea what `navigation` is, because it belongs to Login.js.

I believe passing the navigation object to loginForm.js from login.js will solve this issue:

```
<LoginForm screenProps={{ navigation: this.props.navigation }} />
```

Comment: I followed the instuctions and got the idea about props. But it didn't solved the problem. Still the same error

Comment: Can you successfully pass props into loginForm.js from login.js, using this method or any other?

Comment: thank you! I've spent a night by this question and found the solution. Actually, the main problem was, i hadn't captured props in the child component correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass navigation props to loginForm. It works for me

```
<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```